# Убрать запятую в конце массива

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вывожу данные из массива. При выводе последней строки нужно убрать запятую и пробел (`...</font>,`)

```
success: function(data){
  i = 0;
  while(i < data.length){
    $('#online').append('<font rel="tooltip_bottom" data-original-title="'+ data[i].prj +'"><b>'+ data[i].usr +'</b></font>, '); // вот здесь
    i++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача очень травиальная, гугл в помощь!

```js
var str = 'myLongString, ';
// См. ману: http://javascript.ru/string/substring
var newStr = str.substring(0, str.length - 2); // Берём подстроку от 0 до длины строки минус два; 2 - это число символов с конца, которые нужно удалить хирургически
console.info('Было: "' + str + '"'); // Было: "myLongString, "
console.info('Стало: "' + newStr + '"'); // Стало: "myLongString"
```

**UPD:**

```js
success: function(data){
  var i = 0;
  var tmpStr = '';
  
  while (i < data.length){
    tmpStr += '<font rel="tooltip_bottom" data-original-title="'+ data[i].prj +'"><b>'+ data[i].usr +'</b></font>, ';
    i++;
  }
  tmpStr = tmpStr.substring(0, tmpStr.length - 2);
  $('#online').append(tmpStr);
  // P. S. В цикле вызывать append() - идея так себе, так что так определённо лучше
}
```

Comment: вы говорите про строку, как конкретно в данном массиве это применить

Comment: @Rufex, Код изначально странный. Зачем добавлять код с ошибкой?
Просто уберите запятую и пробел - будет Вам счастье.

Comment: вы понимаете что выводятся поочерёдно элементы массива через запятую, а в конце её нужно убрать

Comment: @Rufex, Я бы так и подумал, именно поэтому и появляются проблемы такого вида, но код-то не такой...
Обычно из массива берут часть, преобразуют её и приклеивают к временной строке. В конце, после обработки массива, её обрезают как я показал и только после используют.

Comment: в моём коде по идее нужно узнать последнюю строку и обрезать, только как

Comment: @Rufex, Ох, блин, обновил код, то?

Comment: вот это то что нужно

Answer (score 4):

Можно просто воспользоваться функцией [`join`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp), она не будет добавлять в конце запятую:

```
function dataToHtml(data) {
    return '<font rel="tooltip_bottom" data-original-title="'+ data.prj +'"><b>'+ data.usr +'</b></font>';
}

data = [{prj: 'Project1', usr: 'User1'}, 
        {prj: 'Project2', usr: 'User2'}, 
        {prj: 'Project3', usr: 'User3'}]

data.map(dataToHtml).join(', ')
```

На выходе получите:

```
<font rel="tooltip_bottom" data-original-title="Project1"><b>User1</b></font>,
<font rel="tooltip_bottom" data-original-title="Project2"><b>User2</b></font>,
<font rel="tooltip_bottom" data-original-title="Project3"><b>User3</b></font>
```